# How to pass list to UserDefinedFunction (UDF) in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to pass a list as arguments for a certain UDF I have in pyspark. Example:

```
def cat(mine,mine2):
     if mine is not None and mine2 is not None:
             return "2_"+mine+"_"+mine2

udf_cat = UserDefinedFunction(cat, "string")

l = ["COLUMN1","COLUMN2"]

df = df.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", udf_cat(l))
```

But I always get an error.

Answer (score 3):

After a while, I figured out that all I need is to pass the list using the character '*' before it. Example:

```
df = df.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", udf_cat(*l))
```

That way, it will work.

Comment: You could as well have a single list parameter in the udf and call it the way you were doing earlier